# Why does my Bash counter reset after while loop

Tags: bash

I have a Bash script where I want to count how many things were done when looping through a file. The count seems to work within the loop but after it the variable seems reset.

```
nKeys=0
cat afile | while read -r line
do
  #...do stuff
  let nKeys=nKeys+1
  # this will print 1,2,..., etc as expected
  echo Done entry $nKeys
done
# PROBLEM: this always prints "... 0 keys"
echo Finished writing $destFile, $nKeys keys
```

The output of the above is something alone the lines of:

```
Done entry 1
Done entry 2
Finished writing /blah, 0 keys
```

The output I want is:

```
Done entry 1
Done entry 2
Finished writing /blah, 2 keys
```

I am not quite sure why nKeys is 0 after the loop :( I assume it's something basic but damned if I can spot it despite looking at http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html and other resources.

Fingers crossed someone else can look at it and go "well duh! You have to ..."!

Comment: <a href="http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024">BASH FAQ entry #24: "I set variables in a loop. Why do they suddenly disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?"</a>

Answer (score 8):

In the just-released Bash 4.2, you can do this to prevent creating a subshell:

```
shopt -s lastpipe
```

Also, as you'll probably see at the link Ignacio provided, you have a [Useless Use of `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat).

```
while read -r line
do
    ...
done < afile
```

Comment: How do you undo this "shopt -s lastpipe" once you're finished using that setting?

Comment: @TimothySwan: `help shopt` reveals that `-u disable (unset) each OPTNAME`, so `shopt -u lastpipe`.

Comment: The link is dead and redirects to an advertisement page. Maybe http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: @DanielBöhmer: Updated link. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the accepted answer, this happens because pipes spawn separate subprocesses. To avoid this, `command grouping` has been the best option for me. That is, doing everything after the pipe in a subshell.

```sh
nKeys=0
cat afile | 
{
  while read -r line
  do
    #...do stuff
    let nKeys=nKeys+1
    # this will print 1,2,..., etc as expected
    echo Done entry $nKeys
  done
  # PROBLEM: this always prints "... 0 keys"
  echo Finished writing $destFile, $nKeys keys
}
```

Now it will report the value of `$nKeys` "correctly" (i.e. what you wish).

Comment: While this works, it's limiting (variables still only live inside the group command), and there are better alternatives: for input from a _file_, use `while ...; do ...; done < afile`, as in Dennis Williamson's answer, for input from a _command_'s output, use a [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution), e.g. `while ...; do ...; done < <(cat -n afile)`.

Answer (score -1):

I arrived at the desired result in the following way without using pipes or here documents

```
#!/bin/sh
counter=0
string="apple orange mango egg indian"
str_len=${#string}
while [ $str_len -ne 0 ]
do
   c=${string:0:1}
   if  [[ "$c" = [aeiou] ]]
   then
       echo -n "vowel : "
       echo "- $c"
       counter=$(( $counter + 1 ))
   fi
   string=${string:1}
   str_len=${#string}
done
   printf "The number of vowels in the given string are : %s "$counter
   echo
```