# How to pipe the output of the Linux which command into the Linux file command?

Tags: linux, file, command, pipe

```
$ which file
/usr/bin/file
$ file /usr/bin/file
/usr/bin/file: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped
```

Why does this not work?

```
$ which file | file

Usage: file [-bcikLhnNrsvz0] [-e test] [-f namefile] [-F separator] [-m magicfiles] file...
   file -C -m magicfiles
```

Try `file --help` for more information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my Bash counter reset after while loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006229/why-does-my-bash-counter-reset-after-while-loop)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`file` expects its arguments on the command line, not on its standard input, unless you tell it otherwise:

```
$ which file | file -f -
```

Alternatively:

```
$ file `which file`
```

Or, for completeness:

```
$ which file | xargs file
```

Comment: $ which file | xargs file   

adding for completeness chose this answer because it has the shortest pipe option.

Answer (score 6):

You're probably looking for xargs or shell expansion. Try:

```
$ which file | xargs file
```

or

```
$ file `which file`
```

Answer (score 4):

Try backquotes instead, e.g.

```
$ file `which python`
/usr/bin/python: symbolic link to `python2.6'
```

Your example doesn't work because your pipe is sending the output of the which command to the stdin of the file command. But file doesn't work on stdin - it works on a command line argument.