# variable reset in a bash script

Tags: bash

a simple variable test:

```
#!/bin/bash

N=0

ls -l | while read L; do
 N=$((N+1))
 echo $N
done

echo "total $N"
```

ran it then output:

```
1
2
3

total 0
```

i expected final N=3: "total  3", but why did the value reset to 0 after the loop?

Comment: solved as a known subshell issue. check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006229/why-does-my-bash-counter-reset-after-while-loop

Comment: you can replace the $((N+1)) with ((N++)) with the same result

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`bash` runs each statement in a pipe in its own subshell. (For external commands such as `ls` the subshell simply `exec`s the command.) This effectively makes all of the variables local. You generally have to work around this by using redirection or command substitution instead of a pipe.

EDIT: This seems to work:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=
N=0

while read L; do
  N=$((N+1))
  echo $N
done <<<$(ls -l)

echo "total $N"
```

EDIT: As of bash 4.2 you can use `shopt -s lastpipe` in your script to disable the subshell for the last command in a pipe, which would then allow the rest of the original code to work as desired.

Comment: What's the logic behind redirection? Why exactly it prevents the while loop from subshelling?

Comment: @olimpiabaku Actually it's piping which makes bash subshell the while loop, although as of bash 4.2 you can disable this in a script (see my edit).