# Unable to get the loop incrementer outside the while loop in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to work on a Shell Script to print the number of vowels in a string for academic purpose ( to teach some one ) , but i am seeing that the value of the loop incrementer ( count variable in the below code ) is not availble outside . 
I tried some other code from different sources , in those examples it is working . 
I think there is some mistake in my code .

I just need help from some one who can have a second look and tell where i am making mistake , i believe it is a semantic mistake.

Following is the code

```
#!/bin/bash
counter=0
echo -n "abcdefghihhdfhkhfdhj" | \
while read -n 1 c; do
    if  [[ "$c" = [aeiou] ]]
        then
        echo -n "vowel : "
        echo "- $c"
        counter=$(( $counter + 1 ))
    fi
done
echo $counter
```

Output :

vowel : - a
1
1
1
1
vowel : - e
2
2
2
2
vowel : - i
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3

0

Comment: This is a [classic pitfall](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#grep_foo_bar_.7C_while_read_-r.3B_do_.28.28count.2B-.2B-.29.29.3B_done).

Comment: Instead of piping `echo` into the loop causing it to be run in a sub shell, you could read directly from a [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).

Comment: I arrived at the desired result in the following way without using pipes or here documents. <br> As i was not able to add the code in this comment i added it here -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/31857806/1966767