# Read command output line by line in sh (no bash)

Tags: sh, io-redirection

I am basically looking for a way to do this

```
list=$(command)
while read -r arg
do
        ...
done <<< "$list"
```

Using sh intead of bash. The code as it is doesn't run because of the last line:

```
syntax error: unexpected redirection
```

Any fixes?

Edit: I need to edit variables and access them outside the loop, so using `|` is not acceptable (as it creates a sub-shell with independent scope)

Edit 2: This question is NOT similar to [Why does my Bash counter reset after while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006229/why-does-my-bash-counter-reset-after-while-loop) as I am not using `|` (as I just noticed in the last edit). I am asking for another way of achiving it. (The answers to the linked question only explain why the problem happens but do not provide any solutions that work **with sh (no bash)**.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my Bash counter reset after while loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006229/why-does-my-bash-counter-reset-after-while-loop)

Comment: Why people mark question as duplicate and vote for closing without even reading? This question has nothign to do with the question linked by @tripleee That is only relevant to show that some of the solutions proposed by others are not correct, and I have already noted it in my question.

Comment: The linked FAQ and the question I nominated as the duplicate target both have workarounds which are not Bash-specific.  Did *you* read *them?*

Comment: @tripleee which one? neither of them applies, the only one is named pipes which leaves files behind

Comment: [Command grouping](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30064493/874188) is a portable and well-documented workaround.

Comment: Command grouping is limiting, you cant do stuff between reading the command output & filling  the variables, and using the variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no purely syntactic way to do this in POSIX `sh`. You'll need to use either a temporary file for the output of the command, or a named pipe.

```
mkfifo output
command > output &

while read -r arg; do
    ...
done < output
rm output
```

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you can't do this?  Should work .. unless you are assigning any variables inside the loop that you want visible when it's done.

```
 command |
 while read -r arg
 do
         ...
 done
```

Comment: Already tried that, the thing is I am assigning variables inside the loop, and I want them visible when it is done D:

Comment: Then I don't see a way to do this without piping the result of `command` to a temporary file first, and using `<` to feed your data into the loop.