# my bash script, in the while structure, the zenity --progress can't work correctly

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I have ever `declare -A` `games_roms games_descriptions games_medias`. They can be generate corretly
when the line 356 is only `done`. But when i redirect the output to `zenity --progress` in the pipeline,those three associative arrays will be empty.
**The answer is read from pipe. But in my question is write to pipe. So it seems the named pipe or  ProcessSubstitution can't solve my problem.**

```bash
   241  function generate_database()
   242  {
   243      exec 3<&0
   244      exec 0<"$1"
   245  #用作打印进度
   246      local -i total_lines=$(cat "$1"|wc -l)
   247      local -i index=1
   248      local key=""
   249      local value=""
   250      local tmp_string
   251      local -i serial_number=0
   252      local OLDIFS=$IFS
   253      IFS=
   254      shopt -s globstar
   255      while read -r line
   256      do
   257  #显示处理进度条
   258          echo $index
   259          ((index++))
   260  #跳过空白行
   261          if [[ "$line" =~ ^[[:space:]]*$ ]]
   262          then
   263              continue
   264          elif [[ "$line" =~ ^game: ]]
   265          then
   266              key=${line#game: }
   267              value="array"$serial_number
   268  #在函数内定义的数组，必须定义成全局变量
   269              eval declare -ag "$value"
   270              let serial_number++
   271              games_roms["$key"]="$value"
   272          elif [[ "$line" =~ ^file: ]]
   273          then
   274              line=${line#file: }
   275  #games_roms 添加roms文件地址，若存在则添加到数组里，若不存在则报错
   276              if [ -e $TRANSF_DIR/**/"$line" ]
   277              then
   278                  tmp_string=`ls $TRANSF_DIR/**/"$line"`
   279                  eval $value[\${#$value[@]}]="\$tmp_string"
   280              else
   281                  echo "file: $line can't be find.">&2
   282              fi
   283  #games_medias   去除rom文件后缀
   284  #games_medias   添加rom文件名对应media下子目录，若目录不存在则报错
   285              line=${line%.*}
   286              if [ -d $TRANSF_DIR/**/media/"$line" ]
   287              then
   288                  tmp_string=`ls -d $TRANSF_DIR/**/media/"$line"`
   289                  games_medias["$key"]="$tmp_string"
   290              else
   291                  echo "derectory: /media/$line can't be find.">&2
   292              fi
   293          elif [[ "$line" =~ ^files: ]]
   294          then
   295              line=${line#files:}
   296              if [[ ! "$line" =~ ^[[:space:]]*$ ]]
   297              then
   298  #这里为IFS赋值旨在去除字符串的前导空格
   299                  IFS=$OLDIFS
   300                  line=`echo $line`
   301  #games_roms 添加roms文件地址，若存在则添加到数组里，若不存在则报错
   302                  if [ -e $TRANSF_DIR/**/"$line" ]
   303                  then
   304                      tmp_string=`ls $TRANSF_DIR/**/"$line"`
   305                      eval $value[\${#$value[@]}]="\$tmp_string"
   306                  else
   307                      echo "file: $line can't be find.">&2
   308                  fi
   309                  IFS=
   310  #games_medias   针对files字段，应该去除rom名，留下rom名前面的目录名
   311  #games_medias   添加rom文件名对应media下子目录，若目录不存在则报错
   312                  line=${line%/*}
   313                  if [ -d $TRANSF_DIR/**/media/"$line" ]
   314                  then
   315                      tmp_string=`ls -d $TRANSF_DIR/**/media/"$line"`
   316                      games_medias["$key"]="$tmp_string"
   317                  else
   318                      echo "derectory: /media/$line can't be find.">&2
   319                  fi
   320              fi
   321  #非空白行，有前导空白的，属于上一个key的值
   322          elif [ "${line:0:1}" == " " ]
   323          then
   324              IFS=$OLDIFS
   325              line=`echo $line`
   326  #games_roms 添加roms文件地址，若存在则添加到数组里，若不存在则报错
   327              if [ -e $TRANSF_DIR/**/"$line" ]
   328              then
   329                  tmp_string=`ls $TRANSF_DIR/**/"$line"`
   330                  eval $value[\${#$value[@]}]="\$tmp_string"
   331              else
   332                  echo "file: $line can't be find.">&2
   333              fi
   334              IFS=
   335  #games_medias   针对files字段，应该去除rom名，留下rom名前面的目录名
   336  #games_medias   添加rom文件名对应media下子目录，若目录不存在则报错
   337              line=${line%/*}
   338              if [ -d $TRANSF_DIR/**/media/"$line" ]
   339              then
   340                  tmp_string=`ls -d $TRANSF_DIR/**/media/"$line"`
   341                  games_medias["$key"]="$tmp_string"
   342              else
   343                  echo "derectory: /media/$line can't be find.">&2
   344              fi
   345          elif [[ "$line" =~ ^description: ]]
   346          then
   347  #games_descriptions
   348              line=${line#description: }
   349  #核对对应的rom地址是否存在，只有rom地址存在才添加描述
   350              eval tmp_string="\${#${games_roms["$key"]}[@]}"
   351              if [ $tmp_string -ge 1 ]
   352              then
   353                  games_descriptions["$key"]="$line"
   354              fi
   355          fi
   356      done|zenity --progress --width=$WIDTH --height=$HEIGHT --title="数据生成中" --text="正在读取游戏数据文件" --percentage=0
   366      shopt -u globstar
   367      IFS=$OLDIFS
   368      exec 0<&3
   369  }
```

I want to display the progress bar correctly.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem is that things in a pipeline (like the `while` loop) execute in subshells. See ["Why does my Bash counter reset after while loop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006229/why-does-my-bash-counter-reset-after-while-loop) and [BashFAQ #24: "I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) Try redirecting to a process substitution instead:`done > >(zenity --progress ... --percentage=0)`

Comment: Please remove all line numbers.